# Pulling Specific User soft Deleted Post from posts table using onlyTrashed method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**I was trying to print all the deleted posts of an admin by onlyTrashed method the code-**

```
Route::get("/admin/{id}",function($id) {
    
     $adminDeletedPosts = User::find($id)->posts()::onlyTrashed()->get();
  
     return $adminDeletedPosts; });
```

it shows an error **-Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::onlyTrashed does not exist.**

Comment: It's not a static method. `User::find($id)->posts()->onlyTrashed()->get();`

Comment: Also look into route model binding, skip the `find()` stuff. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding